# Google Sheets - Conditional custom formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

What conditional formula do I use to only highligh the cells between the FROM and TO dates columns with the colour selected from the Status column. For example, when the status is ONHOLD then cells between the FROM and TO dates are highlighted Orange.

[image]

Comment: Your expected output is achievable through Google Apps Script. Please provide a minumum reproducible example of your Google Sheets so the community will have  better insight on what happens in your sheet and if there is something worth a look if this is done through apps script if you wish to continue.

Comment: you have to create 6 conditional formatting rules. One for each color.

Comment: I'm aware I need 6 rules but what formula do I use to highlight the correct cells in calendar between the FROM and TO dates.

Comment: I do apologize for the incorrect understanding about your question, let me delete my current answer on to remove any possible confusion.

Comment: @GreenDome please provide a minimum reproducible example of your Google Sheet worksheet.

Comment: From my experience, I was able to do a custom formula with Conditional Formatting without a Google Apps Script for a similar use case.  I agree with @ztiaa that you need 6 formulas.  My recommended Google-Fu/GPT-Fu would be "How to do conditional formatting with custom formulas and custom ranges in Google Sheets?".   There's functions that will compare dates and let you know if equal/sooner/later, that works with conditional formatting rules without needing a script.  But there might be unexpected gotchas, so a sample of your sheet will make it easier which direction to go.

Answer (score 0):

The formula I needed was `=AND(G$3>=$E7,G$3<=$F7,$B7=$B$30)`. It checks the date in cell G3 with the dates in the FROM and TO columns then highlights the correct colour from B30. Needed to repeat this rule for each colour.